# Same SQL script but different run time

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm running an SQL script on MS SQL Server, the script is built by joining different tables and writing the output to new tables, i.e. every table has data for one period only. So, I'm splitting the data by periods (periods from 01 to 12). For example, if I ran the script where period = '01', it takes less than one minute to run. The same script where period = '02' on the same database, it took over 5 hours to run an even returned less rows than the previous one!

Any hints or tips will be highly appreciated.

Format of the script:

```
select  a.field1
       ,a.field2
       ,a.field3
       ,a.field4
       ,b.field1
       ,b.field2
       ,b.field3
       ,b.field4
       ,c.field1
       ,c.field2
       ,c.field3
       ,c.field4
INTO Output_Table_Period_01
FROM Table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS b ON a.field1 = b.field1
LEFT JOIN Table3 AS c ON c.field1 = b.field1
WHERE a.field2 = '01';
```

Comment: Can you give us the query plan associated with the query that takes a long time. Probably considering the amount of values SQL decides to use or not an index (or use it a different way). Maybe the joined results are higher also. There are a lot of reasons where two different querys behave differently. You should also make sure statistics are up to date and indexes are properly placed/built.

Comment: if your´re using Microsoft Sql Managment Studio you can hit CTRL + L on the querry to get the execution plan which might give some insights what exactly is taking so long; I would guess its missing indices but then again only knowing the query kind of makes it guessing

Comment: as already been said, if you can provide the actual, not estimated, execution plans for period 01 and 02 and share them here [https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/] then we can see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies. Understand that it's important to check the execution plans, but I can't post them as they contain sensitive data. What things can be checked from the execution plans?

Comment: It would be useful to post the table structures, any indexes, number of rows in each table, any primary / foreign keys etc, basically anything that gives us some more information so that we can help you rather than guess. You might also consider replacing separate tables with 12 views over the base table.